# Count all persons who has ticket filed in last 12 months Grouped per month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have these sample tables:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp_persons (
    PersonID int primary key identity
    , FirstName varchar(max)
    , LastName varchar(max)
)

CREATE TABLE #tmp_tickets (
    TicketNum int primary key identity
    , Title varchar(max)
    , Descr varchar(max)
    , DateFiled datetime
    , SubmittedBy int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES #tmp_persons(PersonID)
)

CREATE TABLE #tmp_assigned_lead (
    AssignmentID int primary key identity
    , PersonID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES #tmp_persons(PersonID) -- ID of the Lead
    , AssignedPersonID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES #tmp_persons(PersonID) -- ID of the person assigned
)

-- DATA DUMP
INSERT INTO #tmp_persons
VALUES
(1, 'John', 'Doe'), (2, 'Jane', 'Doe'),
(3, 'Carl', 'Smith'), (4, 'Jenny', 'Smith'),
(5, 'John', 'Wick'), (6, 'Stephanie', 'Mathews')

INSERT INTO #tmp_assigned_lead (PersonID, AssignedPersonID)
VALUES
(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6)

INSERT INTO #tmp_tickets (Title, Descr, DateFiled, SubmittedBy)
VALUES
('Ticket 1', 'blah', '01-01-2019', 2),
('Ticket 2', 'blah', '01-02-2019', 2),
('Ticket 3', 'blah', '05-01-2019', 4),
('Ticket 4', 'blah', '05-01-2019', 2),
('Ticket 5', 'blah', '06-01-2019', 5),
('Ticket 6', 'blah', '07-01-2019', 6),--
('Ticket 7', 'blah', '4-17-2018', 6),
('Ticket 8', 'blah', '12-30-2018', 6),
('Ticket 9', 'blah', '1-28-2019', 3),
('Ticket 10', 'blah', '3-16-2019', 3),
('Ticket 11', 'blah', '3-30-2018', 5),
('Ticket 12', 'blah', '2-4-2018', 4),
('Ticket 13', 'blah', '1-11-2019', 6),
('Ticket 14', 'blah', '9-5-2018', 6)
```

So here are the points:

- Each person in `#tmp_persons` can have a "lead" and this is stored in
  a relational table `#tmp_assigned_lead`.
- A person can file a ticket
  which is stored in `#tmp_tickets`
- A person is called a `Contributor` when he filed a ticket but goes back as a normal member when he doesnt file another ticket within 12 months.

Now my requirement is, I want to count all persons under a lead which have transitioned into `Contributor` per month. This will be a monthly record.

**Sample Scenarios**:

1. `Person1` was registered `Jan 01, 2018` and has never filed a ticket ever since until just `Jan 01, 2019` when he filed his first ticket. This will consider `Person1` as `Contributor` only for the month of January 2019 but he is a normal member from `Jan 2018` up to `Dec 2018`.
2. `Person1` filed another ticket in `Feb 2019`. Although he filed a new ticket, he is still not counted in `Feb 2019` records of members who became `Contributor` since he is already a `Contributor` in `Jan 2019`
3. `Person2` is registered in `Feb 23, 2019` and immediately filed a ticket. This makes him/her a `Contributor` and is included in the count for "members who became contributors" in the month of `Feb 2019`.

This query I have come up so far groups the tickets per person and month:

```
SELECT
    SubmittedBy
    , MaxDate = MAX(DateFiled)
    , PeriodMonth = MONTH(DateFiled)
    , PeriodYear = YEAR(DateFiled)
FROM #tmp_tickets
GROUP BY
    SubmittedBy
    , MONTH(DateFiled)
    , YEAR(DateFiled)
```

This is where I am at a roadblock. I can't come up with a query will return number of members under a lead, who became `Contributors`.

This is what I have so far. I used the above query as a `CTE`:

```
;with cte as (
    SELECT
        SubmittedBy
        , MaxDate = MAX(DateFiled)
        , PeriodMonth = MONTH(DateFiled)
        , PeriodYear = YEAR(DateFiled)
    FROM #tmp_tickets
    GROUP BY
        SubmittedBy
        , MONTH(DateFiled)
        , YEAR(DateFiled)
)
SELECT
    lead.PersonID
    , ContributorsCnt = COUNT(1)
    , PeriodMonth
    , PeriodYear
FROM #tmp_assigned_lead lead
INNER JOIN cte
    ON lead.AssignedPersonID = cte.SubmittedBy
-- WHERE?? 
-- check if member has no tickets in the past 12 months
GROUP BY
    lead.PersonID
    , PeriodMonth
    , PeriodYear
```

Per data sample here, this is what the records look like in the `cte` above:
[image: cte]

**EDIT**:

> Added data dump and analysis points.

**Points**:

1. On 2018-02, PersonID 4 became a contributor. No one else filed a ticket except him. This will give us a row with:

   `LeadID: 1, PeriodYear: 2018, PeriodMonth: 2, Contributor: 1`
2. On 2018-03, none other than PersonID 5 became a contributor. Again, this will give us another row:

   `LeadID: 1, PeriodYear: 2018, PeriodMonth: 3, Contributor: 1`
3. On 2018-04, PersonID 6, became a contributor:

   `LeadID: 1, PeriodYear: 2018, PeriodMonth: 4, Contributor: 1`
4. From 2018-05 to 2019-01, no one else became Contributor. PersonID 6 here is not counted because he is still a contributor.
5. On 2019-01, PersonID 2 and 3 became contributors. This is their first time filing ticket. Again, PersonID 6 is still a contributor. This will give us row:

   `LeadID: 1, PeriodYear: 2019, PeriodMonth: 1, Contributor: 2`
6. On 2019-02, PersonID 4 is back to being a normal member, not a contributor, since it has been 12 months and he did not file any ticket since then. No row needed for this.
7. On 2019-03, PersonID 5 becomes a normal member (same logic in point #6). Person 3 filed a ticket but he is still a contributor. Overall, no row needed.
8. On 2019-05, Person 2 filed a ticket but he is still a contributor. Person 4 filed a ticket and he is already a regular member so he is now a Contributor:

   `LeadID: 1, PeriodYear: 2019, PeriodMonth: 5, Contributor: 1`
9. On 2019-06, Person 5 becomes a contributor:

   `LeadID: 1, PeriodYear: 2018, PeriodMonth: 5 Contributor: 1`
10. On 2019-07, Person 6 filed a ticket but he is still a contributor since his last ticket was filed on 2019-01. (*What a busy man!*)

**Expected Data Set**:

```
LeadID: 1, PeriodYear: 2018, PeriodMonth: 2, Contributor: 1
LeadID: 1, PeriodYear: 2018, PeriodMonth: 3, Contributor: 1
LeadID: 1, PeriodYear: 2018, PeriodMonth: 4, Contributor: 1
LeadID: 1, PeriodYear: 2019, PeriodMonth: 1, Contributor: 2
LeadID: 1, PeriodYear: 2019, PeriodMonth: 5, Contributor: 1
LeadID: 1, PeriodYear: 2018, PeriodMonth: 5 Contributor: 1
```

I hope this helps clarify my question.

Comment: Thanks for supplying DDL and your attempts, but we don't have any sample data here or expected results. Could you include those too please?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'll try creating data dump for above tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function that gets the list of submitted tickets for the past 12 months

```
ALTER FUNCTION func_isContributor(@dateFiled as DATE, @PersonID as INTEGER)
RETURNS  INTEGER
AS
BEGIN
    return 
        (SELECT
            count(*)
        FROM
            tmp_tickets
        WHERE 
            DateFiled BETWEEN  DATEADD(month, -12, @dateFiled) and  @dateFiled AND SubmittedBy = @PersonID)
END
```

then check if the person has a record for the past 12 months

```
; with cte as (
    SELECT 
        SubmittedBy,
        DateFiled,
        isCounted = case when dbo.func_isContributor(DateFiled,SubmittedBy) -1 = 0 then 1 else 0 END
    FROM
        tmp_tickets
)
SELECT
    lead.PersonID,
        ContributorCount = Count(1),
        PeriodMonth = MONTH(DateFiled),
        PeriodYear = YEAR(DateFiled)
FROM tmp_assigned_lead lead
INNER JOIN cte
    ON lead.AssignedPersonID = cte.SubmittedBy and cte.isCounted = 1
GROUP BY 
    lead.PersonID,
    MONTH(DateFiled),
    YEAR(DateFiled)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a where condition

```
DATEDIFF(MONTH, DateFiled, GETDATE()) <=12
group by MONTH(DateFiled)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep a record about whether a person is a contributor or not. Create another table to keep this records or modify

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp_persons (
PersonID int primary key identity
, FirstName varchar(max)
, LastName varchar(max)
, isContributor int
, contributorSince datetime
```

)

Each time a person creates a ticket check whether it's a time to update `contributorSince` and `isContributor` . If yes update it, otherwise leave it as is.

Group persons by personId and contributorSince (month, year, ...) where isContributor is set to *true* and `contributorSince` is within a timeframe you are interested in.

`isContributor` might not be neccessary. Since you can do it just with `contributorSince`

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not make the requirements as we need a something like history representation of `Contributor` per month.